# BeautifulSoup parsing unicode giving variable results

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to to parse the following ipython notebook however I am getting varying results when I read the unicode into a BeautifulSoup object, i.e.

```
from IPython.nbconvert.exporters import HTMLExporter
from IPython.config import Config
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filepath = '2015-05-01_test2.ipynb'
config = Config({'CSSHTMLHeaderTransformer': {'enabled': True,
                 'highlight_class': '.highlight-ipynb'}})
exporter = HTMLExporter(config=config, template_file='basic')
content, info = exporter.from_filename(filepath)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(content)
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(content)

print(soup == soup2)
print(soup == soup3)
print(soup == soup4)
```

Gives output

```
False
True
True
```

However, if I run the following snippet multiple times the output constantly toggles between a different set of True/False combinations. I am very much at a loss for what could be causing this, has anyone run into this type of issue before?

The relevant notebook can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MatthewGilbert/2ba9f1b7fd89a4911c3e)

### Edit

Upon further investigation, this issue seems to only happen on Linux. I have tried this on Linux Mint and Ubuntu as well as two windows machines and the issue appears to only happen on Linux. Note that I am using IPython 3.0.0 and bs4 4.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another case of [RTM](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems), specifying the specific parser to use seems to solve the problem.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')
```